# select() VS "manual polling" on non-blocking socket

Tags: sockets, network-programming

I've a non-blocking socket used for writing operations (send).

I would like to know if the select() is the only way to detect if:
- the socket connect completed successfully when connect returns EINPROGRESS
- the availability of socket for write operations when send return EWOULDBLOCK or EGAIN

Is polling an alternative to select()? In my application I've already a thread that wakes up each 1 second that can check cyclically if connect() returns with 0 (connection is OK) and send returns with 0 (sending is OK) if some bytes have to be sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is polling an alternative to select()?

It's an alternative, but not a good one. You don't know how long to sleep for. `select()` does. On average a manual poll must sleep for double the required time per attempt, and waste CPU cycles while looping until success. `select()` doesn't have any of those issues.

Comment: Thanks for your useful answer. Luckily in my application, as mentioned above, I've already a "poll thread" that does some stuff. Although (you're right) it will waste CPU cycles, I can add something like this: `code`
while (some condition is true)
 do some stuff;
 call connect;
  if connect does not returns zero
   count failure;
 sleep(1);
end while

while (some condition is true)
 do some stuff;
 call send;
  if send does not returns zero
   count failure;
 sleep(1);
end while
`code`

Comment: Obviously in the previous comment if I reach a threshold failure I exit from the thread loop.